# How to map leader as BackSpace using vim module from lua?

Tags: neovim

I know that in vim I can do

```
let mapleader = "\<BS>"
```

However, using vim module from lua does not seem to work. I tried options such as

```lua
vim.g.mapleader = [[<BS>]]
vim.g.mapleader = [[\<BS>]]
vim.g.mapleader = "\<BS>"
vim.g.mapleader = "<BS>"
```

but none is good.

Answer (score 1):

```
vim.g.mapleader = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<BS>', false, false, true)
```

Credit to https://neovim.discourse.group/t/vim-g-mapleader-bs-not-working/3220/2